# MVC 4 validation message from entityconfiguration

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, validation

This is are the attributes from my model that need validation.

```
    public System.DateTime EntryDate { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime DeadLine { get; set; }
    public string Customer { get; set; }
    public string CustomerContact { get; set; }
```

This is my EntityTypeConfiguration for the validation from these attributes.

```
        this.Property(t => t.EntryDate)
            .IsRequired();

        this.Property(t => t.DeadLine)
            .IsRequired();

        this.Property(t => t.Customer)
            .IsRequired()
            .HasMaxLength(20);

        this.Property(t => t.CustomerContact)
            .IsRequired()
            .HasMaxLength(20);

        this.Property(t => t.InterContact)
            .IsRequired()
            .HasMaxLength(20);

        this.Property(t => t.Category)
            .IsRequired()
            .HasMaxLength(5);
```

How do I get this to work

```
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DeadLine)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The validation rules set within your entity mapping don't bubble up into the UI as you're suggesting in your code. Those rules you've specified are used to create and validate your entity before saving it to your database.

If you wish to validate your entity using the `@Html.ValidationMessageFor()` helper this occurs on the UI layer and instead uses ASP.NET MVC's data annotations to set validation rules, like so:

```
public class Product {
    [StringLength(50),Required]
    public object Name { get; set; }

    [StringLength(15)]
    public object Color { get; set; }

    [Range(0, 9999)]
    public object Weight { get; set; }
}
```

Ultimately, what you want to do is treat your entity separate to the object that gets passed to the UI, by mapping your entity to a view specific model such as a [View Model](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/188/view-model-design-and-use-in-razor-views). you're then able to add the validation attributes highlighted in my answer above to your view model as there may be some circumstances one form requires a field to be required, where as another form might not.

Comment: Thanks it works now I thought there was a way to define the messages in the EntityTypeConfiguration.

Comment: Let me guess that you are placing the attributes on the entity model generated by entity framework. In this way, you will loose your modifications when you have to update the entities. I prefer writing MetaData as mentioned in my Answer. Ignore me, if I am wrong.

Answer (score 0):

There is a solution

Assuming that your entity name is `SampleEntity` you will have your entity like this

```
public partial class SampleEntity{
//..Some other properties
 public System.DateTime EntryDate { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime DeadLine { get; set; }
    public string Customer { get; set; }
    public string CustomerContact { get; set; }
//..Some other properties
}
```

All you have to do write the following code in a separate cs file

```
[MetadataType(typeof(SampleEntity_MD))]
 public partial class SampleEntity
{
}

public partial class SampleEntity{
 [/*Your data validation attribute */]
 public System.DateTime EntryDate { get; set; }

 [/*Your data validation attribute*/]
 public System.DateTime DeadLine { get; set; }

 [/*Your data validation attribute*/]
 public string Customer { get; set; }

 [/*Your data validation attribute */]
 public string CustomerContact { get; set; }
}
```

In this way you are defining the Validation attributes for selected properties, without disturbing your entities generating by the framework..